# Merge data from two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

If I have some data stored in two collections in MongoDB like so:

Collection 1:

```
opened = [{id: 1, value: 1123}, {id: 2, value: 4231}, {id: 2, value: 3322}...]
```

Collection 2:

```
synched = [{id: 1, value: 12343}, {id: 2, value: 12322}, {id: 1, value: 12322}...]
```

Now I know I can make two calls to the db and get the data from both but I am interested in potentially aggregating the call and joining the data from both collections so that I end up with the following result:

```
result = {synched: [{id: 1, value: 12343},{id: 1, value: 12322}], opened: [{id: 1, value: 1123}]}
```

So in my case, currently I am doing a standard query just twice:

```
db.opened.find({id: 1}, function(err, res){})
db.synched.find({id: 1}, function(err, res){})
```

Is there a way to combine those?

EDIT:

The original question that I have posted evolved a little. Here's a slight change that I need to deal with that the below answer doesn't support.

What if I have an array of ids that I am matching:

```
{ $match: { 'id': {$in: [1,2]} }}
```

So now, the `limit` call is really messing this up. What I need is all documents from `synched` and all documents from `opened` that match any of the ids in the array, but doing a limit returns only first encountered. That's not always the case. There might be multiple documents with the same `id` property. That property is not `_id` that is unique.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your mongodb version?

Comment: 3.4.7 is the MongoDB that I am running on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb 3.4 and above

```
db.synched.aggregate([
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$facet": { 
    "synched": [
      { "$match": { "id": 1  }}
    ],
    "opened": [
      { "$match": { "id": 1  }},
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "opened",
        "localField": "id",
        "foreignField": "id",
        "as": "opened"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$opened" },
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$opened" }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": { "opened": 1, "synched": 1 }}
])
```

and with the new [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) syntax

```
db.synched.aggregate([
  { "$facet": { 
    "synched": [
      { "$match": { "id"': { "$in": [1,2] }}}
    ],
    "opened": [
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "opened",
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "id"': { "$in": [1,2] }}}
        ],
        "as": "opened"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$opened" },
      { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$opened" }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": { "opened": 1, "synched": 1 }}
])
```

Comment: thanks you! Now, just a general question about potential db design decision. Would it be better to combine the two data sets into a single collection with additional field `type: synched` or `type:opened` where I could do non-aggregate calls to query both document types, or is aggregate and two collections a good choice here? What's more efficient?

Comment: Aggregation is always a better option. Well It depends upon your project requirement I cannot say anything about this. But about mongodb, splitting of the documents is always a good job (just like sql and its join does) and after that we can easily merge into a single one using `$lookup` and other aggregation tricks.

Comment: apologies but I have modified the question a little bit when I realized that I want to match multiple Ids at once. Can you have another look?

Comment: Ok can you update  your mongodb version to 3.6 or above because what you are trying to do is very much expensive with the above `$lookup` syntax if you can update it to 3.6 or above it would be much easier and time redusing operation.

Comment: This is working well, I did have to make one small change. I had to remove the first `limit` call on the synched pipeline. What was happening is that I wasn't getting any data in the synched array, and all data that matched opened array. Removing the limit call, resulted in all matched documents from synched and all matched documents from opened collections being returned. This is pretty good. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have two collections **Users** and **User Profile**,

The below method will match the requested field also combine the two collections and throw the desired output:

```
const getUserData = async (userId) => {
        const getUserDataByUserId = await userDataModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    userId: userId
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'user_profiles',
                    localField: 'userId',
                    foreignField: 'userId',
                    as: 'users'
                }
            }, {
                $replaceRoot: {
                    newRoot: {
                        $mergeObjects: [{
                            $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0]
                        }, "$$ROOT"]
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $project: {
                    fromItems: 0
                }
            }
        ]);

        return getUserDataByUserId;
    }
```